# Prevent a user from changing a value in a workfow or event receiver

Tags: workflow

I have a workflow on an item and I do certain things when an status column changes.

I need to prevent a user from changing the status to "Witnessed" if they don't fill in the "witnessed person" field.  How can I do this?  I think that if it was in a workflow, that would be too late, because the item would be changed.  Should it be done in an event receiver?  Will this mess with my workflow?  I need them both running at the same time.

Comment: I think to get the best possible answer, you should expand on your requirements a little more.  For example, what are the steps of the workflow? At what stage in the workflow are the witness fields required? Do you prompt for the witness fields when the item is first added, or can you prompt for them from a workflow form after the workflow has started?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to do some validation on your new/edit form so that the field is not editable if they don't fill in a person.